# ¿Cómo se calcula el z-index de un elemento?

Tags: html, css

Voy a poner un ejemplo, en el siguiente código hay tres elementos diferentes, todos con posicionamiento relativo y valores diferentes de `z-index`:

- el menú tiene un valor de 100
- el submenú (sólo activo cuando se pulsa en el enlace) tiene un valor de -1 cuando está oculto, y de 1 cuando está visible.
- el contenido tiene un z-index de 2.

Parecería que al ocultarse el submenú (en cuyo caso su `z-index` sería -1), éste no debería verse ni interferir... pero de hecho se queda por encima del contenido (que tiene un `z-index` de 2) y no deja pulsar sobre el ENLACE.

¿Por qué ocurre eso? ¿Cómo se calcula el `z-index` de un elemento con respecto al del resto de elementos? ¿Cómo afecta el `z-index` de sus ancestros?

```js
$("#opcion").on("click", function() { $(this).toggleClass("active"); });
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html, body {
  background:#eeeeee;
}

#menu {
  height:50px;
  background:white;
  line-height:50px;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}


#menu #opciones {
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  background:white;
  transition: all 1s;
  z-index:-1;
  position:relative;
}

#menu a.active ~ #opciones {
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
  z-index:1;
}

#contenedor {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="opcion">Menu 1</a>
    <div id="opciones">
      <a href="#opcion1">Opcion 1</a>
      <a href="#opcion2">Opcion 2</a>
      <a href="#opcion3">Opcion 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="contenedor">
  <a href="#enlace">ENLACE</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `z-index` suele crear un poco de confusión.

La propiedad `z-index` se aplica a elementos posicionados, es decir, con cualquier valor en `position` que no sea  `static` (la posicion por defecto de los elementos es `static`). No se hereda y aquí surge el primer punto de confusión porque aunque no se hereda si afecta a los hijos, el `z-index` es para un elemento y su contenido, igual que `opacity` o `transform` que afectan a como se ven los elementos hijos porque forman parte del contenido, si pongo `opacity: 0.5` a un elemento todos sus hijos tendrán esa transparencia también.

En tu caso el submenú queda por encima del contenido porque su padre tiene un `z-index` mayor que el contenido que está al mismo nivel. Lo que puedes hacer es quitar la posicion al menú para que su `z-index` no aplique y tenga en cuenta el del submenú y poner un `z-index` a `#opciones` (cuando el enlace tiene la clase `active`) superior al del contenido.

```js
$("#opcion").on("click", function() { $(this).toggleClass("active"); });
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html, body {
  background:#eeeeee;
}

#menu {
  height:50px;
  background:white;
  line-height:50px;
  list-style:none;

}


#menu #opciones {
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  background:white;
  transition: all 1s;
  z-index:-1;
  position:relative;
}

#menu a.active ~ #opciones {
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
  z-index:3;
}

#contenedor {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="opcion">Menu 1</a>
    <div id="opciones">
      <a href="#opcion1">Opcion 1</a>
      <a href="#opcion2">Opcion 2</a>
      <a href="#opcion3">Opcion 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="contenedor">
  <a href="#enlace">ENLACE</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

En principio no es problema del `z-index` en si, si no que el div `#opciones` tiene la propiedad `visibility` cual oculta el elemento, pero sigue conservando el espacio que ocupaba.

Significa que `#opciones` hereda del padre `#menu` cual tiene `z-index: 100;` y por eso el enlace del `#contenedor` nunca se podrá ejecutar.

Lo puedes comprobar si cambias `visibility` a `display`: [Ver ejemplo](http://jsbin.com/sarowa/1/edit?html,css,js,output) cual si funcionaria pero sin el efecto `transition`.

Una la solución sería poner el elemento `<li>` a `height: 0;`

```js
$("#opcion").on("click", function() { $(this).toggleClass("active"); });
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html, body {
  background:#eeeeee;  
}

#menu {
  height:50px;
  background:white;
  line-height:50px;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}


#menu #opciones {
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  background:white;
  transition: all 1s;
  /* Eliminado ya que no afecta
  z-index:-1;
  position:relative; */
}

#menu li {
  height: 0;
}

#menu a.active ~ #opciones {
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
  /* Eliminado ya que no afecta
  z-index:1; */
}

/* Eliminado ya que no afecta
#contenedor {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="opcion">Menu 1</a>
    <div id="opciones">
      <a href="#opcion1">Opcion 1</a>
      <a href="#opcion2">Opcion 2</a>
      <a href="#opcion3">Opcion 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="contenedor">
  <a href="#enlace">ENLACE</a>
</div>
```

La [respuesta de @blonfu](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/39720/6491) funciona pero el problema de su repuesta es que no se respeta el `transition` (ENLACE) al abrir el submenu.

Entonces la otra opción sería dejar solo al `#opciones` la posición `relative`:
(efecto secundario: *less code*):

```js
$("#opcion").on("click", function() { $(this).toggleClass("active"); });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  background: #eee;
}

#menu {
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  list-style: none;
}

#opciones {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: white;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: auto; por defecto */
}

#menu a.active ~ #opciones {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="opcion">Menu 1</a>
    <div id="opciones">
      <a href="#opcion1">Opcion 1</a>
      <a href="#opcion2">Opcion 2</a>
      <a href="#opcion3">Opcion 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="contenedor">
  <a href="#enlace">ENLACE</a>
</div>
```